# Unable to load data Google Colab

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory

I am trying to load data after downloading it through kaggle cli. This exercise is from [this course](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud188/lessons/c5706f76-0e30-4b48-b74e-c19fafc33a75/concepts/80e61337-4d42-4292-9a3b-791f65733d23) on Udacity.

```
!kaggle competitions download -c dogs-vs-cats
!unzip {content}/competitions/dogs-vs-cats/train.zip -d {content}/competitions/dogs-vs-cats/
!unzip {content}/competitions/dogs-vs-cats/test1.zip -d {content}/competitions/dogs-vs-cats/
```

Counting the number of images

```
!ls '{content}/competitions/dogs-vs-cats/train/' | wc -l
# 25000
```

Then I try to load the data

```
data_dir = '{content}/competitions/dogs-vs-cats/train/'

transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(255),
                               transforms.CenterCrop(224),
                               transforms.ToTensor()]) # TODO: compose transforms here
dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(data_dir, transform=transform) # TODO: create the ImageFolder
dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset,batch_size=32,shuffle=True) # TODO: use the ImageFolder dataset to create the DataLoader
```

Error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-9c49d0bdcdb0> in <module>()
      4                                transforms.CenterCrop(224),
      5                                transforms.ToTensor()]) # TODO: compose transforms here
----> 6 dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(data_dir, transform=transform) # TODO: create the ImageFolder
      7 dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset,batch_size=32,shuffle=True) # TODO: use the ImageFolder dataset to create the DataLoader

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchvision/datasets/folder.py in __init__(self, root, transform, target_transform, loader, is_valid_file)
    207                                           transform=transform,
    208                                           target_transform=target_transform,
--> 209                                           is_valid_file=is_valid_file)
    210         self.imgs = self.samples

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchvision/datasets/folder.py in __init__(self, root, loader, extensions, transform, target_transform, is_valid_file)
     95         if len(samples) == 0:
     96             raise (RuntimeError("Found 0 files in subfolders of: " + self.root + "\n"
---> 97                                 "Supported extensions are: " + ",".join(extensions)))
     98 
     99         self.loader = loader

RuntimeError: Found 0 files in subfolders of: {content}/competitions/dogs-vs-cats/train/
Supported extensions are: .jpg,.jpeg,.png,.ppm,.bmp,.pgm,.tif,.tiff,.webp
```

Comment: This answer in this [question ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54613573/runtimeerror-found-0-files-in-subfolders-of-error-about-subfolder-in-pytor) will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using f-strings in a wrong way. Simply add `f` here:

```
data_dir = f'{content}/competitions/dogs-vs-cats/train/'
```

to include `content` value to the path; without `f` you are just using `{content}/competitions...` string as a path, as you can see in your error message.